# How to count all characters in all rows of a field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to character count the sum of all the characters in a text based field in MySQL. I need to know the total number of characters of all the posts in that field combined, and can't think how I'd do this...

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "all posts in that field"? normally a field would contain a single entry, be that a "post" or anything else.

Comment: Well, yes chhh. It does contain a single entry. I said post instead. Is that ok?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For the number of bytes . . .

```
select sum(length(your_column_name)) 
from your_table_name;
```

For the number of characters . . .

```
select sum(char_length(your_column_name)) 
from your_table_name;
```

The [char_length() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) accommodates multi-byte characters; five two-byte characters will return as 5.

Comment: Oh sweet, yes he said "sum of all the characters", so LENGTH would give an incorrect result. I've took the liberty to update my answer to use CHAR_LENGTH, because it's what is needed, and I pay a +1 :-)

Answer (score 5):

Just sum all the lengths for the field

```
SELECT SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(field)) FROM table
```

Comment: [Length()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_length) returns the number of bytes, not the number of characters. (Except by coincidence.)

Comment: yes, I noticed and updated the answer. funny we commented each other's post at exactly the same time.

Answer (score 2):

[CHAR_LENGH(column)](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-char_length-function.php) counts with spaces. In account to count all characters expect spaces first we have to remove spaces. Hope this helps.

```
SELECT SUM(char_length(REPLACE(column, ' ', ''))) FROM table
```